# LLVM IR printing a number

Tags: assembly, llvm, bytecode

I'm trying to print a number, but I'm getting errors saying my print function is wrong:

```
define i32 @main() {
entry:
  %d = shl i32 2, 3
  %call = call i32 (i8*, ...)* @printf(i8* %d)
  ret i32 1
}

declare i32 @printf(i8*, ...)
```

And here's the error:

```
Error in compilation: /bin/this.program: llvm.ll:4:44: error: '%d' defined with type 'i8'
  %call = call i32 (i8*, ...)* @printf(i8* %d)
                                       ^
```

Is there some other print function that fixes this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LLVM IR has no implicit casts (and explicit casts are separate instructions).
Your `%d` variable has type `i32`, from the first instruction (it's odd that error message is `'%d' defined with type 'i8'`, probably your example is not your real code?).

As for `printf` function, it is exactly C [printf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/). And you should pass exactly the same arguments - a format string (`i8*` pointing to null terminated `"%d"`), and a number.

For string, you should define global

```
@formatString = private constant [2 x i8] c"%d"
```

And pass it as first argument to `printf`:

```
%call = call i32 (i8*, ...)* @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([2 x i8], [2 x i8]* @formatString , i32 0, i32 0), i32 %d)
```

Full code:

```
@formatString = private constant [2 x i8] c"%d" 

define i32 @main() {
entry:
  %d = shl i32 2, 3
  %call = call i32 (i8*, ...)* @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([2 x i8], [2 x i8]* @formatString , i32 0, i32 0), i32 %d)
  ret i32 1
}

declare i32 @printf(i8*, ...)
```

Comment: This code produces the following error code: "expected comma after getelementptr's type". Specifically, it points to needing a comma right before the format string. Any thoughts?

Comment: @ErikP. It's either me not testing the code, or LLVM IR format change. You could use clang with `-emit-llvm` to get an idea of how it should look now: https://godbolt.org/g/yoYBiS

Comment: It looks like we need to add the type to the start of the format string: `%call = call i32 (i8*, ...)* @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([2 x i8], [2 x i8]* @formatString , i32 0, i32 0), i32 %d)`